# problem with Routing HTTP API Examples

Tags: ios, cloudmade

i have followed this example to try to trace the itinerary between two points :

```
http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/routing-http-api/examples
```

However in the example there is no notification of where to put the http query : `http://routes.cloudmade.com/YOUR-API-KEY-GOES-HERE/api/0.3/start_point,[[transit_point1,…,transit_pointN]],end_point/route_type[/route_type_modifier].output_format[?lang=(en|de)][&units=(km|miles)]`
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

there are query examples like

http://routes.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/0.3/47.25976,9.58423,47.26117,9.59882/car.js

Find more: http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/routing-http-api/examples/query-examples

Hope that helps!